# What does rtorrent's system.method.set_key, get_base_path, etc. mean?

Tags: rtorrent

rtorrent's web site has this example of a configuration rule to move a completed torrent:

```
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,move_complete,"execute=mv,-u,$d.get_base_path=,~/Download/;d.set_directory=~/Download/"
```

Is the format of this command documented anywhere? I cannot find what `$d.get_base_path` means anywhere, or why it's `$d` in one spot and just `d` in another spot, for example.

Answer (score 2):

http://community.rutorrent.org//RtorrentScripting would be what you're looking for, if more people contributed what they know. As of now, it has a few hints collected from the mailing list and other places, and is incomplete.

The same is true for https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/Scripting-Guide.

Comment: Here's a link to a more up to date (and accessible) wiki page: https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/User-Guide

Answer (score 1):

One is a variable and one is setting a variable.

`$d.get_base_path=` is a variable that has a value that is being called.

`d.set_directory=~/Download/` is having a value assigned to it.

Now as to what the `$d.get_base_path=` means, got to your ncurses interface look around your info on your running torrents until you find the base path.